# Typescript Internal Module Across Multiple Files In Nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp, visual-studio-code

I've been pouring through StackOverflow posts and multiple blog posts, but can't seem to find the answer.

I'm using VS Code, nodejs, typescript and gulp.
When I place all of my module Controllers code into one file like this:

```
 <controllers.ts>
 module Controllers {
    export class Api {
         get(controllerName:string):IController {
         }
    }   
 }

 module Controllers {
    export interface IController {
        performAction(actionName:string):any;
    }
 }

 module Controllers {
    export class ControllerBase implements IController {
        performAction(actionName:string):any {
    }
  }
}

module Controllers {
    export class UserController extends ControllerBase {
    }
}

export = Controllers;
```

Gulp is able to compile it and nodejs runs it correctly.

When I break it into multiple files though, I can't seem to get it to compile:

```
<controllers.ts>
module Controllers {
    export class Api {
         get(controllerName:string):IController {
         }
    }   
}

module Controllers {
    export interface IController {
        performAction(actionName:string):any;
    }
}

module Controllers {
    export class ControllerBase implements IController {
        performAction(actionName:string):any {
        }
    }
}

export = Controllers;

<UserController.ts>
module Controllers {
    export class UserController extends ControllerBase {
    }
}
```

I've tried adding

```
/// <reference path="./controllers.ts" />
```

to the top of my UserController.ts file. When I do that, it still can't find ControllerBase.

I tried doing

```
export class Controllers.UserController extends Controllers.ControllerBase
```

and it doesn't like the Controllers before UserController, but if I remove that Controllers and make it look like this:

```
export class UserController extends Controllers.ControllerBase
```

then obviously it places UserController in a different module.

Also, importing it like this:

```
import Controllers = require("./controllers");
```

doesn't seem to help either. I'm not sure what else to try. Any help would be greatly appreciated. It doesn't seem like this shouldn't be achievable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at doing something like this, there seem to be two issues.

1. Intellisense in your coding tool of choice and
2. Compilation.

For my scenario, intellisense isn't a concern, because I shouldn't need intellisense on the functions in the base class for the classes that extend the base class. Compilation was my big struggle. Here is the solution I came up with. I don't love it, but it does seem to work.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var insert = require('gulp-insert');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var del = require('del');

var tsOptions = {
    noImplicitAny: true,
    target: 'ES5',
    module: 'commonjs'
};

gulp.task('clean', function(done) {
    del(['./dest'], done);
})

gulp.task('compile-controllers', function() {
    return gulp.src(['./src/controllers.ts', './src/*.ts'])
               .pipe(concat('controllers.ts'))
               .pipe(insert.append('export = Controllers;'))
               .pipe(ts(tsOptions))
               .js
               .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/server'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Typescript Internal Module Across Multiple Files In Nodejs

Don't. Use `external modules` with the compiler flag `--module commonjs` instead : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

If you are still not convinced here are more reasons : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

Comment: Thanks for your response. I watched your video and read your post, but still don't know how to achieve what I would like. I would like to define a variable/unknown number of Controllers that can all extend the ControllerBase. I want them to live in separate files to allow small focused files but have them all live under the same module('namespace'). Is this achievable? It seems from your post that --out would be the approach I would have to take, but it isn't recommended because you can't guarantee build order and that could cause lots of issues. Is there any way around this?